# How to search an entire repository which contains folder named "trunk" in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

How can i get the list of all paths of repositories( each repo has branches,tags,trunk) in a file.

We have a huge repository and i am trying to get the list of all paths of repositories which has "trunk" folder name specifically.

i tried using svn list with grep but how do i get to the root level and search for this folder name and get the path of every repository that has this folder name.

i saw in couple of blogs that i use SVN tree as well.

if anyone could help me with an example that would be great.
i am new to SVN so apologies if my verbiage is not understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have WC of *any node* of this super-repo, your can get repo-root (in rather fresh SVN):

```
WC\trunk\Sub>svn ls -R "^/"
branches/
branches/sprint01/
branches/sprint01/Sub/
branches/sprint01/Sub/c.txt
branches/sprint01/a.txt
branches/sprint01/b.txt
tags/
trunk/
trunk/Sub/
trunk/Sub/c.txt
trunk/a.txt
trunk/b.txt
```

Regexp for grep, which will collect only `trunk/` (`SOMENAME/trunk/` in your use-case, AFAICR), nor `trunk/Sub/` nor `trunk/a.txt` is also easy work after `man grep`